# Sort array of objects by array of IDs

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-5

Is it possible, rather easily, to sort an array of objects by an array of IDs? Here's an example:

```
[{
    id: "A",
    name: "John"
}, {
    id: "B",
    name: "Bobby"
}, {
    id: "C",
    name: "Peter"
}]
```

Now I have an array of objects, each with an unique ID. I then have an array of IDs like so:

```
var ids = ["C", "A", "B"];
```

Would it be possible to sort the array of objects, so it ends up like this:

```
[{
    id: "C",
    name: "Peter"
}, {
    id: "A",
    name: "John"
}, {
    id: "B",
    name: "Bobby"
}]
```

Comment: [`arr.sort((a, b) => ids.indexOf(a.id) > ids.indexOf(b.id))`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2uqhnnqy/)

Comment: `data.sort(function(a,b) { return ids.indexOf(a.id) > ids.indexOf(b.id); })`

Comment: Also see [Sort array containing objects based on another array](//stackoverflow.com/q/13518343), [How do I sort an array of objects based on the ordering of another array?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9755889), [Sort an array of objects based on another array of ids](//stackoverflow.com/q/35538509), [JavaScript - Sort an array based on another array of integers](//stackoverflow.com/q/4046967)

Answer (score 18):

You could order it with an object for the sort order.

```js
var data = [{ id: "A", name: "John" }, { id: "B", name: "Bobby" }, { id: "C", name: "Peter" }],
    ids = ["C", "A", "B"],
    order = {};

ids.forEach(function (a, i) { order[a] = i; });

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return order[a.id] - order[b.id];
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you have only the same amount of `id` in the `ids` array, then you could just rearrange the array with the assigned indices without sorting.

```js
var data = [{ id: "A", name: "John" }, { id: "B", name: "Bobby" }, { id: "C", name: "Peter" }],
    ids = ["C", "A", "B"],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    result[ids.indexOf(a.id)] = a;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the second solutions takes n^2, so it could be unperformant